# How to create an array with particular item from a dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am having the details of the members as a dictionary.i want to add an array with particular object from the dictionary.The response i am having is like this,

```
{
    500 =     {
        name = baddd;
        status = "<null>";
    };
    511 =     {
        name = abyj;
        status = "Hi all...:-)";
    };
    512 =     {
        name = abyk;
        status = fdffd;
    };
}
```

I want to create an array with the results of name only.i have tried like this

```
for(int i=0;i<=self.currentChannel.memberCount;i++)
{

    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.currentChannel.members objectForKey:@"name"]] ;  
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
    [searchfriendarray addObject:name]; 


}
NSLog(@"%@",searchfriendarray);
```

but the value added is null. can anybody help me ?

Comment: The problem with your code seems to be that you do not use the array index anywhere. To enumerate a dictionary, it is easiest to use the `for...in` syntax. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse `objectEnumerator` to get the values (inner dictionaries). Then just add the value of "name" to the resulting array. Example (assuming the dictionary is named `d`):

```
 NSDictionary* d = ...
 NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:d.count];
 for(NSDictionary* member in d.objectEnumerator) {
     [array addObject:[member objectForKey:@"name"]];
 }
```

Comment: it will be great if u edit my code ,so that i am not getting u?

Comment: I is difficult to say exactly how you should edit your code since I am not sure how your class is defined. In general, `d` above is whatever your dictionary is (my guess is `self.currentchannel.members`, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Krumelur was faster than me ;) He is right by saing that you should traverse the dictionary values first. In your implementation you don't reference your counter variable i somewhere, so the NSString name is the same in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```
// here you can get Array of Dictionary First
     NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@""]; // get array first from your response
     NSDictionary *temp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.currentChannel.members];
    for(int i=0;i<=self.currentChannel.memberCount;i++)
    {

        NSDictionary *temp = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[temp objectForKey:@"name"]] ;  
        NSLog(@"%@",name);
        [searchfriendarray addObject:name]; 


    }
    NSLog(@"%@",searchfriendarray);
```

Thanks.